# omega-guard fails to start - needs omega module enabled

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drush

I have a single site drupal 7 installation with omega 4.

If I use omega as the default theme, drush omega-guard works just fine, however if I set a subtheme (created with omega-wizard) default it fails to run:

Command omega-guard needs the following module(s) enabled to run:    [error]
omega.
The drush command 'omega-guard' could not be executed.               [error]

what should I fix?
thx

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu I had the same problem and used `bundle exec guard` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with command: drush cc drush